# How to change checkbox checked color with react?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, styled-components

There is a checkbox component:

```
import React, { InputHTMLAttributes } from "react";
import styled, { css } from "styled-components";

export const CheckBox: React.FC<InputHTMLAttributes<HTMLInputElement>> = (
  props
) => {
  return <Input type="checkbox" {...props} />;
};

const Input = styled.input`
  ${({ theme }) => css`
    border: 1px solid white;

    &:checked {
      background-color: green;
      border-color: green;
    }
  `}
`;
```

I want to set its checked color to another but doesn't work. It's still the default blue background color.

---

I hope:

Before

[image]

After

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to style a checkbox using CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4148499/how-to-style-a-checkbox-using-css)

Comment: @jsejcksn `accent-color` doesn't work for my requirement. I only want to set the mark and border color.

Comment: You should conditionally render two icons one if checkbox is checked and second when checkbox is not checked

Comment: If you want to example snippet then let me know into comment

Comment: @AnujPanwar Yes, if you can show me an example will be very helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> You can create own your component for that but it takes a lot of time.

[Checkout into sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/reverent-snowflake-7kvu37)